# Zero Width Height jPanel on start

Tags: java, swing

Why does the jPanel return 0 for the height and width when it starts and how can I get the right values on start.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class ZeroJPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form ZeroJPanel
     */
    ZeroJPanel() {
        initComponents();

        System.out.println( this.getHeight() );
    }


    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        new ZeroJPanel();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: A panel won't have a size until the frame has been realized, which means it has been packed or made visible. Why do you care? Let the layout manager do its job.

Comment: Because I generalized the problem.

Comment: You can add an `AncestorListener` to the panel. Then when the panel is made visible you can get its actual size.

Comment: *"Because I generalized the problem"*  In your mind, does that explain anything?  It means nothing to me.  I've been programming Java since before 2000.  I've developed 100s of GUIs and helped with 1000s of GUI problems.  I have yet to see ***one,*** where it was necessary to know the panel size prior to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The panel returns `0, 0` because, quite simply, that is the default value.

When you add the panel to a frame, and call `pack()` on the frame, that will calculate the correct (preferred) size and set it. Until then, you won't be able to find the size because it hasn't been calculated.

Why do you need these values? If you can explain the problem in broader terms, we may be able to help you.